# IE7 CSS Hover Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have created two menus, a horizontal drop-down and a vertical menu, these both work fine in IE8, Chrome and Firefox but I'm getting a weird issue in IE7.

You can view a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5y7vt/3/

In IE7 on the horizontal menu, hover over Link 2 and the dropdown appears however when you move down the dropdown it disappears when over the vertical navigation below.

In addition the dropdown links only hover when over the text, not the rest of the block.

Is anyone able to look and see why this is occurring?

**Answer:** Removing position: relative; from #nav ul li {} fixed the dropdown issue

Comment: ie7 doesn't support ‘:hover‘ on non anchor elements.

Comment: If that was the case why does it work on some links but not others?

Comment: Not sure, wasn't willing to wade through all the code. You'd likely get a better response with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) rather than the entire website code.

Comment: Ok thanks steve, if I get no responses I'll update with a shorter example if I can

Comment: @steveax - yes it does. IE6 is the one that has this problem; it was fixed in IE7.

Comment: @Spudley yep, my mistake. In standards mode ie7 does indeed support hover on non-anchor elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `position: relative;` from `#nav ul li {}` fixed the dropdown issue

Comment: Well done for finding the answer -- I was well on the way to getting there, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you Spudley, I appreciate the time you spent on the solution.